# How to inject the "resolver-calling instance" as constructor parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is it possible to resolve a dependency with unity and pass information of the "calling instance" to the constructor of the service to resolve?

Lets say I've got an implementation (`Log`) of an `ILog` interface with a construtcor takeing a parameter.

```cs
class Log : ILog
{        
    public Log(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

`Log` will be injected into the two Test classes by unity.

```cs
class TestA
{
    private statig Ilog _log;

    public TestA(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;    // <-- _log.Name = "TestA"
    }

}

class TestB
{
    private statig Ilog _log;

    public TestB(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;    // <-- _log.Name = "TestB"
    }

}
```

Is it possilbe to access the instances of TestA and TestB within the registration of the `Log`-Type to pass the Name to the constructor?

I thought of something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<ILog, Log>(new InjectionConstructor( x => x.GetType().Name ));
```